# How to start/stop/restart Linux services and how to update their configuration files from a Java program

Tags: java, linux, service, configuration

I am looking for a portable way to update the configuration files of a Linux service e.g., ssh, and then restarting that service from a Java program. For example, the Java program fetches some user names from a remote database, updates the AllowUsers directive of the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and then restarts the ssh service.

Especially if you can point me to an API that can manage the text based conf files from a Java program, that will be great. Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, the more important part is the periodic update of the configuration file from a Java program, not the start/stop of the service bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good place to start: [Comparison of Open Source Configuration Management Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software)

Most configuration management systems are written in scripting languages (Perl, Python, etc), but the list contains two libraries written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can process files with standard classes like `BufferedReader` and `StringTokenizer` for splitting.

To execute commands, `Runtime` or `ProcessBuilder` classes.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. I am aware of the classes  in java.io for file handling, what I wanted to know was some automated or periodic way of configuration management in Java. Doing it manually using java.io classes sorts of defeat the purpose, basically I will have to create the API I am looking for.